# Relation between flag varieties of Langlands dual groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flag-varieties

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb C$ and let $G^\vee$ be its Langlands dual group. What are the precise relationships between the complete flag variety $X$ of $G$ and the flag variety $X^\vee$ of $G^\vee$? Are there interesting morphisms of varieties that connect them?

Apologize if the question is vague. I am new to Langlands dual groups, but recently discovered that some properties of modules of $\mathfrak g$ can be related to Schbert cell structures on the dual side. It will also be appreciated if anyone can point out references on relationships between geometries of $X$ and $X^\vee$.